# PHP Session not Recognized During AJAX Request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, session-variables

I've created a navigation bar where an admin can add and remove links with a simple form. When the form is submitted to add a link, an AJAX call is made to add the new information into the mySQL database. As part of the callback function, the navigation bar is updated to include the new link using the following line of code:

```
$('.nav ul').load('/getnav.php');
```

The  file getnav.php is as follows:

```
<?php
  require('/connect.php');
  $query = "SELECT id, title, url
            FROM nav
            ORDER BY position ASC";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);

  while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if (!empty($_SESSION['valid']))
           echo '  <div class="container"><button type="button" name="'.$data['id'].'" class="delButton" alt="Delete"></button></div>
';
  echo '  <a href="'.$data['url'].'" alt="'.$data['title'].'">'.$data['title'].'</a>
';
}
?>
```

The issue is that when the nav bar is updated in the AJAX call, only the links are being shown, and the delete buttons disappear. `$_SESSION['valid']` is set, so the code right after the if SHOULD be executed. However, it's that if's code that is missing after the AJAX call is made. The only explanation I have for this is that when getnav.php is being loaded into `.nav ul`, the session isn't being accessed. Anyone know why that is?

Comment: Did you start a session anywhere in getnav.php? I see you trying to access a session variable but until the session is started you can't

Comment: Oh that's probably it. I was using `require('getnav.php')` in the html and had already started a session on that page so I had to get rid of it in getnav.php. I'll have to work that in somehow and see if that's the issue.

Comment: So I have to have `session_start()` on the html page, I have to have `require('/getnav.php')` on the page, and getnav.php also has to have `session_start()`. Any ideas on how to accomplish this without destroying the session, and obviously without calling session_start() twice on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to diagnose without the full code.

- Did you start the session with session_start(); ?
- Can you try to var_dump $_SESSION?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I can create a version of getnav.php which does not have `session_start()` and will be used when I call `require('/getnav.php');` on the html page. Then I create another version of getnav.php which does have session_start() and includes the original, which will be used for the AJAX call .

It should fix the problem, although it isn't really a satisfactory solution. Better suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out.

By using `session_write_close();` after the first session_start(), I'm able to use session_start() again in getnav.php without any errors.